# How can I configure logout functionality in spring security with thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am new here I just want to know where I go wrong In configuring the Logout part in spring, I made a loging form form patient but when I try to logout it promt a 404 page.

Here is my Source Code.

##### Controller

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/patient")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PatientLoginPage {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String patientLoginPage(Model model) {
//        model.addAttribute("successRegistration", true);
        return "PatientWebPages/PatientLoginPage";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login-error")
    public String errorPatientLoginPage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("errorMessage", true);
        return "PatientWebPages/PatientLoginPage";
    }

    @GetMapping("login-success")
    public String successPatientLoginPage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("successRegistration", true);
        return "PatientWebPages/PatientLoginPage";
    }
}
```

##### Security Config

```java
import com.capstone.dentalclinic.demo.security.PasswordEncoder;
import com.capstone.dentalclinic.demo.services.patient.PatientServicesImpl;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.DelegatingServerLogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.SecurityContextServerLogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.WebSessionServerLogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
@Order(1)
public class PatientSecurityConfig {

    private final PatientServicesImpl patientServicesImpl;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProviderPatient() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder.bcryptPasswordEncoder());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(patientServicesImpl);
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChainPatient (HttpSecurity http) throws  Exception{
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/patient/login", "/patient/registration", "/Service",
                    "/patient/login-error", "/patient/login-success", "/forgot-password", "/new-password").permitAll();

            http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProviderPatient())
                .antMatcher("/patient/**")
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAnyAuthority("PATIENT")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/patient/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/patient/dashboard", true)
                .failureUrl("/patient/login-error")
            .and()
            .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/patient/login")
//                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
//                            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
//                            .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer1() {
        return (web) -> web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**","/static/**", "/static/*", "/static/", "/css/**", "/assets/**",
                        "/javascript/**");
    }
}
```

##### dashboar.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/assets/administrator/new-resized-logo.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="16x16" href="/assets/administrator/new-resized-logo.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

   

    <!--Bootstrap CDN -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- CSS Link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/patients/PatientDashboard.css}">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/admin-system/src/main/resources/static/css/patients/PatientDashboard.css">

</head>
    <body>
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-danger opacity-100">
            <div class="container-sm">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/patient/dashboard">
                    <img th:src="@{/assets/patients/logo.png}" width="85" height="85" alt="Logo">
                </a>
                    
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>  
                
                <div class=" collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto ">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link shadow-text mx-2" aria-current="page" href="#profile">PROFILE</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link shadow-text mx-2" href="#record">RECORDS</a>
                    </li>
                        <a class="button-logout shadow-text mx-3" th:href="@{/logout}">LOGOUT</a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Navbar -->

        <!-- Main dashboard -->
        
        <div class="container-md mt-5 mb-5">
            <div class="header">
                <h1 class="text-center fw-bolder display-4 p-5">Welcome to<br>Patient Dashboard</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Tables -->
        <div class="container-md mt-5 w-auto" id="profile">
            <table class="table table-borderless table-hover">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center fw-bold h2" colspan="4" scope="col">Basic Information </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-start fw-bolder w-25 fs-5" >First Name</td>
                        <td class="text-center w-25 fs-5" th:text="${data.firstName}"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-start fw-bolder w-25 fs-5">Middle Name</td>
                        <td class="text-center w-25 fs-5" th:text="${data.middleName}"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-start fw-bolder w-25 fs-5">Last Name</td>
                        <td class="text-center w-25 fs-5" th:text="${data.lastName}"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-start fw-bolder w-25 fs-5">Suffix</td>
                        <td class="text-center w-25 fs-5" th:text="${data.suffix}"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-start fw-bolder w-25 fs-5">Date of Birth</td>
                        <td class="text-center w-25 fs-5" th:text="${data.birthDate}"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-start fw-bolder w-25 fs-5">Gender</td>
                        <td class="text-center w-25 fs-5" th:text="${data.gender}"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-start fw-bolder w-25 fs-5">Civil Status</td>
                        <td class="text-center w-25 fs-5" th:text="${data.civilStatus}"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-start fw-bolder w-25 fs-5">Physical Disability or Condition</td>
                        <td class="text-center w-25 fs-5" th:text="${data.physicalDisability}"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="container-md mt-2 w-auto">
            <table class="table table-borderless table-hover">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center fw-bold h2" colspan="4" scope="col">Contact Information</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-start fw-bolder w-25 fs-5">Email Address</td>
                        <td class="text-center w-25 fs-5" th:text="${data.emailAddress}"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-start fw-bolder w-25 fs-5">Complete Address</td>
                        <td class="text-center w-25 fs-5" th:text="${data.homeAddress}"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-start fw-bolder w-25 fs-5">Phone Number</td>
                        <td class="text-center w-25 fs-5" th:text="${data.contactNumber}"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- Tables -->

    </body>
</html>
```

##### pom.xml

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.capstone.dentalclinic</groupId>
    <artifactId>admin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>admin</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Am I missing something ? Please Enlighten me.

I tried and watch many tutorials but still can fix it.

Comment: show us what your request looks like in the webbrowser F12/Network tab

Comment: it show 404 in status, GET in method and name is logout.

Comment: im sorry, but i did not ask for your description of what it said, i asked for you to SHOW US what the request looks like so that is can do my own analysis of what the request looks like thank you.

Comment: @Toerktumlare it looks like this "http://localhost:8080/logout"

Comment: you dont seem to be able to produce what im asking for, good luck.

Comment: @Toerktumlare sorry but I cant post Imges in comments,

Comment: You do know there is an edit button on your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your application is looking for a "logout" page that you don´t have, hence 404.
Why? Because in your `securityFilterChainPatient` you put this: `.logoutUrl("/logout")`

Remove `.logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()`

The application will apply the standard logout procedure and then go to "/patient/login"

Answer (score 0):

change :

```
.logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/patient/login?logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll();
```

You can also try to remove this section in config file. It will automatically redirect to login page

````
.logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/patient/login")
//                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
//                            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
//                            .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");```
````